# Possible to create burn-after-execute temp file in one line?

Tags: bash, temporary-files

I have a lot of (virtual) machines to initialize, so I wrote an init script and put it on a web server. Usually I paste the following four lines as one line to console, so that the VM can be initialized expected.

```
TEMPFILE = `mktemp`
curl http://host/path/to/init.sh > $TEMPFILE
sh $TEMPFILE
\rm $TEMPFILE
```

How to write it more elegant and compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pipe `curl`'s output to the shell:

```
curl http://host/path/to/init.sh | sh
```

No tempfile is needed.

---

However, this is potentially insecure because a hacker might modify `init.sh` during transmission and will be able to execute arbitrary code on your system then. I would at least suggest to use `https`

Comment: never though it can be so easy

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it straight to `sh`

```
curl http://host/path/to/init.sh | sh
```

Comment: As both answers are identical, but hek2mgl seems to be earlier to answer, so I have to his. Thanks you anyway.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 Yes, hek2mgl's answer was posted 23 seconds before mine : ) Additionally the edits to his answer make it much better than mine anyway.